# Oracle multiple inserts, different ids

Tags: oracle, insert

I want to move some data from one table to another. I wrote a query that I think will work, but in the destination table, there is a column that contains an id. I want each row I insert to have a different and consecutive id. Here is a simplificated example:

```
Table1
Name Telephone Actie
Peter 123456 Y
Michael 111111 Y
George 1234445 N

Table2
Id Name Likes
1 Peter Books
2 Michael Books
```

The query I wrote:

```
insert all into table2 (name, likes)
select all.name name, 'Books' likes, from (select o.name
  from table1 o where o.active='Y') all;
```

Is there any way of generating the consecutive ids and use the "insert all into" query? A sequence? If it can be made with a sequence... is there any way of doing it without a sequence?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to generate id's in Oracle is by using a sequence.

```
create sequence seq_table2_id nocache;
```

Then upon inserting call seq_table2_id.nextval.

```
insert into table2 (id, name, likes)
select seq_table2_id.nextval
,      o.name
,      'Books'
from   table1 o
where  o.active = 'Y'
```

Personally I use a trigger to automatically call the sequence on inserts, but there are people who dislike using triggers.

Comment: The answer is good, but I was expecting to do this without the use of any sequence, even knowing that this is the optimum solution.

Comment: There's no reason to create a sequence for a one-off, single-session insert. ROWNUM is perfectly "proper" in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROWNUM:

```
insert into table2 (id, name, likes)
select ROWNUM, all.name name, 'Books' likes from (select o.name
  from table1 o where o.active='Y') all;
```

I'm not sure why you have the subquery (perhaps your real query is more complex?)  You could write:

```
insert into table2 (id, name, likes)
select ROWNUM, o.name, 'Books' likes 
  from table1 o where o.active='Y';
```

Comment: Yes, as you said my query is more complex indeed... maybe the example i've put is not the best. I rewrote my query using ROWNUM and it works just as I wanted to! Thank you for your answer.